# Kivymd MDSegmentedControl size

Tags: kivy, kivymd, segmentedcontrol

I'm trying to use the MDSegmentedControl but can't figure out how to adjust the overall width. It just runs off the screen when placed next to another widget.

```
KV = '''
MDScreen:
    
    
    
    MDCard:
        MDLabel:
            size_hint: None,1
            width: 200
            text: 'Gender'
        
        MDSegmentedControl:
            adaptive_width: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    
            MDSegmentedControlItem:
                text: "Male"
    
            MDSegmentedControlItem:
                text: "Female"
                
 
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to give a fixed width of the segment panel children: https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/segmentedcontrol/segmentedcontrol.kv#L34

Its width is set as `320dp`, no matter what size you give to the **MDSegmentedControl** widget.

So once the widget is created, adjust the width of the `segment_panel` children by yourself:

```py
sc = MDSegmentedControl(size_hint_x=None, width=dp(200))
sc.ids.segment_panel.width = dp(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
sc = MDSegmentedControl(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}, size_hint=(1,None))
sc.ids.segment_panel.pos_hint = (1,1)
```