# KivyMD: how can I change active item of MDSegmentedControl

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I don't know how to change active (selected) segment of `MDSegmentedControl` in KivyMD without touching it (e.g. after loading data from db and opening a screen). I can set `current_active_segment` property to one of the `MDSegmentedControlItem`s but it has no impact on UI. Example code below:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.input.providers.mouse import MouseMotionEvent
from kivy.clock import Clock

kvFloatLayout = """
MDScreen:
    id: mdscr
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height: True
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        spacing: "12dp"
        
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: top_app_bar
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            title: "Test App"
            elevation: 4
                        
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            adaptive_height: True
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            padding: "12dp", "0dp", "12dp", "12dp"
            spacing: "12dp"
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: btn_resize
                text: "Resize"
                on_release: app.seg_resize()
               
            MDRaisedButton
                id: btn_change
                text: "Change selection"
                on_release: app.seg_change_selection()
                
            MDSegmentedControl:
                id: seg_options
                MDSegmentedControlItem:
                    id: sci_option1
                    text: "Option left"
                MDSegmentedControlItem:
                    id: sci_option2
                    text: "Option right"
                    
"""

class TestApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kvFloatLayout)

    def seg_resize(self):
        #Workaround from stackoverflow (size not working in .kv - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74999000/kivymd-mdsegmentedcontrol-size)
        self.root.ids.seg_options.ids.segment_panel.width = (Window.width - dp(24))
        
    def seg_change_selection(self):
        sc = self.root.ids.seg_options
        print("---sc:")
        print(sc)
        sci = self.root.ids.sci_option2
        print("---sci:")
        print(sci)
        print("---sc.current_active_segment before:")
        print(sc.current_active_segment)
        sc.current_active_segment = sci
        print("---sc.current_actilve_segment after:")
        print(sc.current_active_segment.text)
        #A poor workaround with mouse click:
        #Clock.schedule_once(self.simulate_mouse_click, 1)
     
    def simulate_mouse_click(self, *args):
        x = 0.75*Window.width
        y = Window.height - \
            self.root.ids.top_app_bar.height - \
            self.root.ids.btn_resize.height - \
            self.root.ids.btn_change.height - \
            dp(12) * 3 - 40
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 0, (x,y))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (x,y)
        touch.x = touch.px = touch.ox = x
        touch.y = touch.py = touch.oy = y
        print("---touch")
        print(str(touch))
        Window.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)
        #1/0
        
TestApp().run()
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

The only way I was able to make it work was scheduling a mouse click over the right segment item but of course this is far from being a good and reliable solution. It is this part of code:

```
#Clock.schedule_once(self.simulate_mouse_click, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that the designers of the `MDSegmentedControl` did not allow for the utility that you want. Another way to trick the `MDSegmentedControl` into thinking that it has been clicked on is to create a `FakeTouch` class:

```
class FakeTouch(object):
    pass
```

And then, use that class in your `seg_change_selection()` method:

```
def seg_change_selection(self):
    sc = self.root.ids.seg_options
    print("---sc:")
    print(sc)
    sci = self.root.ids.sci_option2
    print("---sci:")
    print(sci)
    print("---sc.current_active_segment before:")
    print(sc.current_active_segment)
    # sc.current_active_segment = sci
    touch = FakeTouch()
    touch.x = sci.center_x
    touch.y = sci.center_y
    sc.on_press_segment(sci, touch)
    print("---sc.current_actilve_segment after:")
    print(sc.current_active_segment.text)
    # A poor workaround with mouse click:
    # Clock.schedule_once(self.simulate_mouse_click, 1)
```

Similar to your simulated mouse click, but perhaps a but simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I marked it as answer because it confirms there is no such functionality and I really like your improvement on finding the coordinates of the touch object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found also `ToggleButton` behaviour in KivyMD documentation which I played with and I think it is also a good alternative for `MDSegmentedControl`. I can use `state: "down"` attribute to easily control which button/segment is pressed. One may want to play further with it but the below form is similar enough to `MDSegmentedControl` for my purposes. The attached image shows how it looks like.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.input.providers.mouse import MouseMotionEvent
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.behaviors.toggle_behavior import MDToggleButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRaisedButton
 
kvFloatLayout = """
MDScreen:
    id: mdscr
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height: True
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        spacing: "12dp"
        
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: top_app_bar
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            title: "Test App"
            elevation: 4
                        
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            adaptive_height: True
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            padding: "12dp", "0dp", "12dp", "12dp"
            spacing: "12dp"
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: btn_resize
                text: "Resize"
                on_release: app.seg_resize()
               
            MDRaisedButton
                id: btn_change
                text: "Change selection"
                on_release: app.seg_change_selection()
                
            MDSegmentedControl:
                id: seg_options
                MDSegmentedControlItem:
                    id: sci_option1
                    text: "Option left"
                MDSegmentedControlItem:
                    id: sci_option2
                    text: "Option right"
                    
            MDBoxLayout:
                id: lay_toggle
                adaptive_height: True
                width: top_app_bar.width
                spacing: "8dp"
                padding: "4dp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest
        
                MyToggleButton:
                    text: "Show ads"
                    width: lay_toggle.width / 2 - lay_toggle.padding[0] - lay_toggle.padding[2]
                    group: "x"
                    allow_no_selection: False
                    on_press: self.md_bg_color = app.theme_cls.bg_dark
        
                MyToggleButton:
                    text: "Do not show ads"
                    width: lay_toggle.width / 2 - lay_toggle.padding[0] - lay_toggle.padding[2]
                    group: "x"
                    allow_no_selection: False
                    on_press: self.md_bg_color = app.theme_cls.bg_dark
                    state: "down"
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_dark
"""
 
class MyToggleButton(MDFlatButton, MDToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.background_down = self.theme_cls.primary_color

class FakeTouch(object):
    pass

class TestApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kvFloatLayout)
 
    def seg_resize(self):
        #Workaround from stackoverflow (size not working in .kv - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74999000/kivymd-mdsegmentedcontrol-size)
        self.root.ids.seg_options.ids.segment_panel.width = (Window.width - dp(24))
        
    def seg_change_selection(self):
        sc = self.root.ids.seg_options
        sci = self.root.ids.sci_option2
        touch = FakeTouch()
        touch.x = sci.center_x
        touch.y = sci.center_y
        sc.on_press_segment(sci, touch)
        
TestApp().run()
```

[MDSegmentedControl vs MDToggleButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7s2T.png)